# Is there any way to save bangali Language content in database without encoding?

Tags: php

Is there any way to save Bengali Language content in database without encoding, like: আমার will be saved exactly as আমার. But it is inserted as à¦—à¦²à§à¦ªà§‡ à¦—à¦²à§à¦ªà§‡ à¦¸à¦¿ à¦ªà§à. it is being coded before save but how could I prevent this automatic encoding?

Comment: Which database system are you using? How have you created the database (it should be at least UTF-8)? Provide the "CREATE DATABASE" statement (or the equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would prefer using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). So before it is sent to the DB, I'll use:

```
urlencode($content);        // %E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0
```

And while displaying:

```
echo urldecode($content);   // আমার
```

**Output:**

- https://ideone.com/O8UaTl
- https://ideone.com/TBvy1z

This way, it is safe to be stored. But only one issue is, the content's length in URL Encode will be larger than the original one.

But the right way, is to use UTF8-MB4 or similar Encoding in the Database. Eg. in MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `whatever` (
  -- Fields
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```